# Including 3D figures -- "click to activate"

Tags: animations, movie15

When I use Asymptote to create 3D figures, they appear in the final PDF as static images. When the user hovers the mouse over them, the message "click to activate" is displayed and a mouse click transforms them into rotatable and zoomable interactive figures.

I want to achieve the same thing with my U3D files which I include using `movie15`:

```
\includemovie[
poster,
text={\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{fig/mystaticversionof3dfile}},
toolbar, 
label=my3dfile.u3d,
3Drender=SolidWireframe,
3Daac=30.000000, 
3Droll=270.000000, 
3Dc2c=86.22 -21.6 1.95, 
3Droo=60.169449, 
3Dcoo=-15.000000 3.500000 15.000000,
3Dlights=CAD,
]{\linewidth}{0.5055\linewidth}{figures/my3dfile.u3d}
```

This figure automatically converts into an interactive figure if the viewer supports it. This is bad if the user opens the document to print it. What parameters do I need to change to introduce the "click to activate behaviour"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to leave out the `poster` option. It interferes with the `text={...` option.